# How to get the compressed WIF of my key?

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, base58check

I'm a trying to understand the different encoding on the private keys. What format is used by the [iancoleman](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/) validator and why? How can I reproduce it?
All my Data is valid.

According to the [bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoinwiki.org/wiki/Bitcoin_address#How_to_create_Bitcoin_address.3F) The procedure to create a bitcoin address is as follow

[image: Bitcoin address creation]

It seams to me that I have achieve all that with the following code;

First I generate a mnemonic and seed with [BIP39](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bip39).

```
    exports.seed = async () => {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        const mnemonic =  bip39.generateMnemonic(); 
        const seed =  bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic); 
       resolve(seed)
      });
    }
```

The mnemonic produced

> drive captain sustain winner neutral anchor congress skirt buzz usage
> orient wood

The seed

> c981bc6db5b0680aa96140f2c9f5f0b910ff69157b01b4de24f9e7590950f44c300386362a0e4ecf109b4c770e74efe81c0b1f673e3de8d1d82a687b1c0d206d

Now I use that seed to generate a key pair with [hdkey](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hdkey)

```
exports.key = async (seed) =>{
  return new Promise(resolve => {
  
    const hdkey = HDkey.fromMasterSeed(Buffer.from(seed))
    const masterPrivateKey = hdkey.privateExtendedKey
    const addrnode = hdkey.derive("m/32'/0'/0'/0")                    // derived path
    const nodePubKey = addrnode.publicExtendedKey  


    const sha256 = createHash('sha256').update(nodePubKey).digest()
    const pipedMd = createHash('rmd160').update(sha256).digest()      // 20 bytes hash
 
   
    var fingerprint = Buffer.allocUnsafe(21)                          // fingerprint 20+1 bytes

    fingerprint.writeUInt8(0x00, 0)                                   // 0x00 network byte
    pipedMd.copy(fingerprint,1) 


    var sha1 = createHash('sha256').update(fingerprint).digest()
    var sha2 = createHash('sha256').update(sha1).digest()
    var checksum = sha2.slice(0,4)                                  // checksum 4 bytes

    var rawAddr = Buffer.allocUnsafe(25)                            // raw address 25 bytes

    fingerprint.copy(rawAddr,0)                                     // fingerprint 21 bytes + checksum 4
    checksum.copy(rawAddr,21) 

    var address = bs58check.encode(rawAddr)                         // base58 encode the raw address

    resolve(address)
  })
}
```

So what I can validate so far is that according to this [BIP39 validator](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/)

- The seed generated by the mnemonic is good
- The `masterPrivatekey` is the BIP 32 root key (as per validator)
- Both xpub and xprv key are valid with this derivedpath `"m/32'/0'/0'/0"`

The address resolve in

**1XNR1ABuzSKp4tb3WpF9Yrj88ZBSxMYQ3BnHjtn**

This is not a valid address it has 39 characters. The validator, Under the BIP32 tab returns

**1B4CKfR96isLCXET5D8jykA2Yz3DBhxAZX**

I'm not sure how this address is generated. I think i might be missing a layer in the keys?

Should I use the BIP32 extended xpub key and derive some more keys out of it. My reasoning behind this is
that I derived a keys pair from  `m/32'/0'/0'/0`

The validator return a different address with this path `m/32'/0'/0'/0/0`

So the problem has to be from the concatenation of the networkid + fingerprint + checksum or the base58 encoding. I'm also not sure if the network byte should be added to the fingerprint before the 2 SHA256 hash checksum or after.

This are the 2 other modules I use;

[bs58check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bs58check)
[create-hash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-hash)

**UPDATE**

Changed the bs58check for [base58-encode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base58-encode)
I am getting the right address length
By pointing that first address to `m/44'/0'/0'/0/0`  i have finally obtained
A valid address and a public key

> Address 1HaGGkWmUDTKExFxyXaiGHHPxYNaCefQrj

> Public Key 02a84461e76ba44d674d5915b9b48b1bbc0b9b09ccd8e83a43f6d2a42cae78e806

But the private key is wrong, if I read this account private key like this

```
const nodeAcc = hdkey.derive("m/44'/0'/0'/0/0")
const nodeAccPubKey = nodeAcc._publicKey.toString('hex'))
const nodeAccPrvKey = nodeAcc._privateKey.toString('hex'))
```

**The private key I get from my code**

> 6301454cea9ddf9318e7ac82fdfb6edefbf2984384a05c37bdf79258d2331464

IT seams to me I'm not getting the right format. The private key the BIP39 validator is giving me for my address is this

> KzYASafouu8yEFUByEt3g9XMAGtbAfqQqgmQxDct4h4kgQzKiXDY

If I encode that private key in the base58 format I get

> 7fUVBZBe47GfV2oMe9RWWaQvBpfh3r2EQuSnv1vCyuqd

I also found this article that uses [WIF format](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format)

They basically say that to generate a WIF private key I have to repeat the Network byte and checksum process. I don't understand why in the case of the address generation we use the network byte `0x00` and for the WIF Private key we use `0x80` Both are for main network?

I could validate my WIF with this [tool](https://gobittest.appspot.com/PrivateKey)
My private key WIF

> 5JZtXicXZq4crDo32sGeJw3LyUchpWBy9mMV5op6gMQWP636o2m

So I am wondering which encoding is use by iancoleman's app

I validate my private Key in the Hex format
I Validated my WIF
I have Validate the import process from another wallet (Electrum)

I know that in the end the key will be used in the byte format but I would still like to understand why I'm not able to match it to the validator

Comment: I don't see why you think the private key is "wrong", it is actually the key for `1HaGGkWmUDTKExFxyXaiGHHPxYNaCefQrj`.

Comment: Which one is good? The last one is from the validator an KzYA.....
The one I get is 63014...

Comment: That’s the private key in hex format.

Comment: ok So what format is the KzY one so I can reproduce it.

Comment: that’s just base58.

Comment: If I encode it to base 58 i still get a different value
7fUVBZBe47GfV2oMe9RWWaQvBpfh3r2EQuSnv1vCyuqd

How could you tell that this key was good?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116999/discussion-between-madeindreams-and-anonymous).

Comment: So if it's just base58 why cant'i reproduce it by encoding my key to base58 instead of Hex ?? My WIF is valid and it is not that.

Comment: I think you should start with understanding addresses and WIFs before trying to roll your own from an xpub or xprv.  Your hex private key 6301454cea9ddf9318e7ac82fdfb6edefbf2984384a05c37bdf79258d2331464 has a compressed WIF: KzYASafouu8yEFUByEt3g9XMAGtbAfqQqgmQxDct4h4kgQzKiXDY, Addr: 1HaGGkWmUDTKExFxyXaiGHHPxYNaCefQrj , and the uncompressed WIF: 5JZtXicXZq4crDo32sGeJw3LyUchpWBy9mMV5op6gMQWP636o2m, Addr: 16HUmgrkTeMCK4aaCrmjracBhw2MVWm2Z9

Comment: So how do I generate the compressed version of it? And what is it used for. It doesn't look any smaller than the uncompressed version. I am further in the code now and I validated my wallets against Electreum and Metamask. I could import both and got all the right adresses along so my understanding is a bit further now. This is also what I'm asking. How to get the compressed version.